# Rails + React + real time validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I have a rails 5 + react application. In this application I would like to introduce validation.

Let's say I have a product model that has a price that must be greater than 0 and less than 5 or equal to 20.

I have 2 instances when I will validate the product model on creation:

1. When everything is submited. I will validate in rails and I will send a message back to react telling the react part that yes it was ok 200, or no, this entity is not ok 422 + the errors in json format which can be mapped to the form fields
2. When the user is actually typing. Let's say the user introduces 55 for the price which is greater than 20 so I want to instantly display that the price entered is not valid.

These both are very clear to me how to do them. I have some real time validations on the react side for the form and some backend validations that await for the submission of the form. Problem is I have to have the validation data(in this case the numbers 0, 5, 20) in both react and rails.

I have been thinking that maybe I can put these 'magic' numbers in an yml file and export them to react.

Is this the right approach? Does anyone have a better idea on how to store these values that must be in both react and rails ?

Comment: you can do the validation in the front end like you said but you MUST do it in the backend otherwise people will make a script and throw what they want inside of it

Comment: very correct i do both front end and backend. I think i didn't manage to explain my issue clearly.

Issue is both these validations use same numbers and I don't want to define them in both the front end and back end. I need to put them somewhere so both rails and react have access to them. I was thinking of am yml file ...

Comment: Why not just make a request to the API to see how many are in stock? i don't think you need a middleman, you just need to have somewhere a state with the stock available and refresh any time someone enters the page add form

Comment: no no. You don't get me. I am on the product creation page. I want to create a product. My validation states that it can't have a price higher than 50. I do not want to have this 50 in 2 places(front end + backend) yet i need to instantly show the error to the user. I would rather not make an api call to check the field once the field is completed so I must have only 1 place to store these validations

Comment: Ok i see what you mean now, the way i usually deal with this that comes to my mind is to create a file called contants and put the constant values there and from there you can import them. But to be fair i'm not too sure you could import in both frontend and the backend

Comment: ok I see. This is the .yml file idea. If i make a file I have them in backend and I can import them in the front end then. Thx @RicardoCosta

Comment: not a problem, not sure if i was much help but you are welcome :)

Comment: having an idea validated is very helpful :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass your validations to React either as props or data attributes if your Rails app serves HTML, or in the JSON if it's a Single Page App (SPA).

Continue to validate server-side as well as it's dangerous to perform client-side only validation as it can be bypassed with direct server calls.

If you're passing JSON with constraints, you might want to consider a structure that would mimic available [html5 validation attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern#Attributes) or your custom validation names.

```
{
  "product": {
    "attributes": {
      "name": {
        "type":"string",
        "pattern":"[A-Za-z]",
      },
      "price": {
        "type":"decimal",
        "max":"20.00",
        "min":"5.00",
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: My react and rails apps are separated. 2 different entities. So I would have to serve react a json with the validations.

Comment: How would you see this done? Something like:
{
  product_validation_constants {
    product_price_gte: 0,
    product_price lt: 20
  }
} in the json response?

Comment: @LucianTarna Expanded my example with how I would pass validations in an example system. Make it more or less verbose as suits your situation.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a form system like Formik you can serve a dynamic validation script by ssr. The usual way this is managed anyway is to keep validation separated

Comment: We use redux-form for form management. I do not know what ssr means, can you point me to a source of documentation ?

Comment: ssr = Server Side Rendering. That means rendering your ReactJS into HTML inside of Rails which can be done in [react-rails](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails) gem.